# Stored procedure doesnt return any value

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, datatable, objectdatasource

I got simple problem but I got no idea about where is problem :/ So in my `GridView` I am using `ObjectDataSource` with custom paging like in this tutorial http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/180_Custom_GridView_Paging_with_ObjectDataSource_Control_with_ASPNet_20.aspx

Here is my aspx markup:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" 
        runat="server" 
        onselecting="ObjectDataSource2_Selecting"
        EnablePaging="true"
        SelectCountMethod="GetItemsCount"
        SelectMethod="BindItems"
        StartRowIndexParameterName="startRowIndex"
        MaximumRowsParameterName="maximumRows"
        TypeName="eSova.Utilities.RecordUtilities" 
         >
```

And method which calling:

```
  public static DataTable BindItems(int category,int search,int startRowIndex,int maximumRows)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
        {
            ConnectionUtilities.OpenConnection(connection);
            SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetItems",connection,transaction);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add("@RowIndex", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = startRowIndex;
                command.Parameters.Add("@MaxRows", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = maximumRows;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(table);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
```

My stored procedure works just fine and return in all items from table.

But when I analyze the code, I got breakpoint on return and table variable is without records. I don't know where is problem.

UPDATE:

```
create proc [dbo].[GetItems](@RowIndex int,@MaxRows int) 
as 
    declare @StartRows int 
    declare @EndRow int 

    set @StartRows=(@RowIndex+1) 
    set @EndRow=(@StartRows+@MaxRows) 

    select * 
    from ( select  id, name, filepath, descript, itemlanguage, 
           filetypeid, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER by id)as row  FROM Items)as NumberesItems 
    where row between @StartRows and @EndRow
```

Comment: Why are you sing a `SqlTransaction` on a select?  Are you getting an exception?  If you are, your current code is swallowing that exception.  Use the catch block to **catch** the exception, in addition to anything else you may want to do in the event of an error.

Comment: If you're not breaking in the program until the return line, chances are something happened above that threw an exception and then undid the select.  Put a breakpoint at the the start of the method and step through the code to see what is going on.

Comment: Good point, SqlTransaction its just messy code from another method which i recode, But if delete SQLTransaction i got still the same result! No error no exception but variable table is empty ={} so I guess adapter is also empty and StoredProcedure doesnt call at all

Comment: Have you stepped through the code?  You indicate that the stored procedure works correctly - you tried it in SQL Server Management Studios?

Comment: yes i stepped my code. BUt i dont get it where i set maximumRows for storedProcedure which i tried in SMS but i set exactly value for aprametrs 0 and 20 for example. my procedure is in update

Answer (score 0):

Your connectionstring is empty.

Comment: Not necessarily - `ConnectionUtilities.OpenConnection(connection);` most likely initiliazes it.

Comment: OK guys ty everybody for help but i know where is the problem. StoredProcedure was fine and problem happend between show this table through GridView:)